# DefaultValue react useform from map object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to get values of map object and assigned to useform defaultValue.

```
     const def = jobdetail.defect_details;
     const sample = def?.map((item) => {
     return {
              defects: item.defects,
              recommendation: item.recommendation,
              photo: []
          };
      });

    const defects_json = JSON.stringify(sample);
    const output = defects_json?.replace(/"(\w+)":/g, '$1:');

    // result of const output when console.log(output) 
    [{defects:"defect 2",recommendation:"recomendatin 2",photo:[]},{defects:"defect1 ",recommendation:"recommendation 1",photo:[]}]
```

this is my useform

```
      const {
             register,
             formState: { errors },
             handleSubmit,
             reset,
             control,
             getValues,
             setValue,
     } = useForm({
        shouldFocusError: false,
         defaultValues: {
         defectslist: output, // its empty
         partslist: [
           { sorCode: "", item: "", quantity: "", rates: "", subtotal: "" },
         ],
      },
  });
```

Hope someone can help me to why const output is empty in useform defaultValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already fixed this issue. I need to pass object to reset() from useEffect to re-render the values:

```
 const {
   register,
   formState: { errors },
   handleSubmit,
   control,
   getValues,
   setValue,
   reset,
   initialState
 } = useForm();


useEffect(() => {
    reset(jobdetail);
}, [jobdetail])
```

Answer (score 0):

the keys of your `defaultValues` need to correspond to the `name` prop of your input components. So your defaultValues object essentially needs to look something like this:

```js
{
  defects0: "defect 2",
  recommendation0: "recomendatin 2",
  photo0: []
  defects1: "defect 2",
  recommendation1: "recomendatin 2",
  photo1:[],
  sorCode: "",
  item: "",
  quantity: "",
  rates: "",
  subtotal: ""
}
```

And you html must look something like:

```
<input name="defects0" ref={register}>
<input name="recommendation0" ref={register}>
```

To achieve the first one you can do something like this:

```js
const defaultValuesObj = { sorCode: "", item: "", quantity: "", rates: "", subtotal: "" }
def?.forEach((item, i) => {
 defaultValuesObj[`defects${i}`] = item.defects
 defaultValuesObj[`recommendation${i}`] = item.recommendation
 defaultValuesObj[`photo${i}`] = item.photo
});
```

and you can do `defaultValues: defaultValuesObj`

Comment: defectslist and partslist is a useFieldArray.     const {
    fields: defectsFields,
    append: defectsAppend,
    remove: defectsRemove,
  } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "defectslist" });

  const {
    fields: partsField,
    append: partsAppend,
    remove: partsRemove,
  } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "partslist" });